# how to save chats for a unique user in core data and fetch when needed swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

According to my requirement I have to save all chat of the user in core data with userid and when again visit users page then have to fetch the previous chat via user ID.

I have Chats Entity that is having msg, userType and time Attributes.
[image]

which I have to save in Users entity as like each message(Chats object) of the user should save in Users and can be refetch using Unique ID of user from core data.

[image]

Below code I am using for saving the data.

```
func saveDataToModel(msg:MessagesData)
    {
        let chats = Chats(context: context!)
        chats.msg = msg.message
        chats.userType = msg.userType

        users?.userChats = chats
        if let ids = viewModel?.userSelected?.id
        {
            users?.id = Int16(ids)
        }

        //saveContext()
        do {
            try context?.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed saving")
        }
    }
```

And Below code for fetching

```
func getDataFromCoreData() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Users")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        do {
            let result = try context?.fetch(request)
            if (result != nil) {
                for data in (result as? [NSManagedObject])! {
                    print("data",data)
                }
            }
        } catch {

            print("Failed")
        }
    }
```

Below is the struct

```
struct MessagesData {
    var message:String?
    var userType:String?
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why are you using an extra `Transformable` struct rather than a Core Data relationship? A relationship is much more efficient. And why don't use use a more specific `NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>` or even `NSFetchRequest<Users>` rather than most unspecified `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`? To filter data you have to add a **predicate**

Comment: so where is the problem ?